# Rails/SQL: How to find the most frequent column value on a specific id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, orm

I'm trying to find the most frequent Title for a specific SongId in my table in Ruby on Rails. This is what I have so far:

```
SongDetail.where(song_id: id).group('title').order('COUNT(*) DESC').first[:title]
```

I keep getting an error that reads:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "song_details.id" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by will group your record with distinct column, but here in your query postgres is confuse to select which `song_details.id` from group of `title`, so get rid from this following is trick

```
SongDetail.where(song_id: id).group('title').order('COUNT(*) DESC').select('title').limit(1)
```

Comment: Welcome @dcporter7